# Можно ли считать личной беседу двух людей с помощью соответствующих устройств, например web камер ноутбуков?

Tags: грамотная-речь

[Некоторые вопросы можно решить только в **личной беседе**. Благодаря камере HP HD с широким динамическим диапазоном вы всегда будете...](https://hp-rus.com/catalog/noutbuki/hp-470g8-uma-i7-1165g7-470-g8-17-3-fhd-ag-uwva-3001/)

Можно ли считать личной беседу двух людей с помощью соответствующих устройств, например web камер ноутбуков?
Я думаю нет, так как беседа осуществляется посредством устройств, а не непосредственно.

Answer (score 1):

В одном из многих значений (https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE) Лицо — человек вообще, человек, как отдельный индивидуум:

> Нечего делать, Акакий Акакиевич решился пойти к значительному лицу. / Н.
> В. Гоголь

Беседу личностей  (личность — отдельное человеческое «я») в любых обстоятельствах можно назвать личной.

Comment: Беседой считается чат в телеграмме?

Comment: Не по адресу вопрос: я — из числа *громадян похилого віку*, сидел только за телеграфным аппаратом. Думаю, не всякий разговор беседа, но всякая беседа разговор.

Answer (score 1):

Если беседа доступна только её участникам, думаю, можно. *Лично* = *без посредников*, посредником же может быть только человек, а не какой бы то ни было способ связи. Иначе и переписка не считалась бы «личной».